# php simple html dom - extracting more attributes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Here's an example of the page that I need to extract data with simple html dom:

```
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/games/game1"><img class="nimg" src="http://www.domain.com/content/icons/game1.jpg" alt="Play Cool game" />
  Cool game</a></li>
```

I need url, jpg and title (cool game), not alt.

So far I found only solutions that managed to extract only one attribute, `href`:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)      $links[] = $element->href;
```

Comment: Try $html->find('a', 1) to get the first element

Comment: one element is not a problem. we need help matching all elements - url, image, title

Comment: @Peter - that would get the second `a`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $links[] = array(
        'href' => $element->href,
        'title' => $element->title,
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $img = $element->find('img',1);
    $games[] = array(
        'url'   => $element->href,
        'img'   => $img->src,
        'title' => $element->plaintext
    )
}
```